# Foreach Counting how many times 1 items comes in array

Tags: php, loops, foreach, explode

Im trying to get a count in a foreach

like this
in the array
 Item 1
 Item 1 
 Item 2
 Item 3
 Item 3
 Item 3
 Item 3

Now these items comes from an explode

```
 $likes = explode(',', $user_likes);
```

then i have

```
foreach($likes as $like){

  echo $like.'<br>';

}
```

What i want as output is

item 1 (2)
item 2 (1)
item 3 (4)

So no double items but with how many times that item is in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
print_r(array_count_values($likes));
```

If you want it to be formatted like item 1 (2) item 2 (1), etc, do the following:

```
$valueCount = array_count_values($likes);
foreach ($valueCount as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." (".$value.") ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for but can you help me with sorting for highest number to lowest ?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php. Set $valueCount = arsort(array_count_values($likes));

Comment: That dossen't seem to work Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() i

Comment: $count = array_count_values($likes);
         arsort($count);
this works thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$scores = array();

foreach($likes as $like){
    if(!isset($scores[$like]))
    {
        $scores[$like] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $scores[$like]++;
    }
}

print_r($scores);
```

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
<?php

// Counter
$i = '0';

// Array
$array = 'apple, grape, pair, plum';
$array = explode(",", $array);

// Loop
foreach ($array as $value)
  {
      $i++;
      echo '<p>#' . $i . ' - ' . $value . '</p>';
  }

?>
```

Would output something like this...

```
#1 - apple

#2 - grape

#3 - pair

#4 - plum
```